# Como pasar de horario mexico a utc en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

tengo una consulta donde desde java server faces lo estoy pasando como horario de mexico, y lo que quisiera hacer es convertir la hora que me llega por medio de la vista en jsf con primefaces que es horario mexico a utc, miren, les paso mi consulta:

```
-- FUNCTION: public.sp_get_reports_currents_informations(character varying, character varying, character varying)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.sp_get_reports_currents_informations(character varying, character varying, character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_get_reports_currents_informations(
    in_begin_date character varying,
    in_end_date character varying,
    cves character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(var_json jsonb) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
var_jsonresp jsonb:='[]';
JSON_ARRAY_CVES JSON := $3::json;
BEGIN
SELECT COALESCE(array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(det))),'[]') FROM 
                        (SELECT cv.vehicle_name AS vehiculo, 
cc.company_name AS empresa,
COALESCE(extract (week from tlm.send_time)::text,'-') AS semana,
(SELECT out_company_name FROM sp_get_company_fathers_reports(cv.origin_adm)) AS grupo,--Se manda a llamar el sp donde trae el nivel mas superior que tiene esa compañia                         
COALESCE(ce.employee_name, '-') AS operador,
COALESCE(to_char(tlm.send_time at time zone 'CST' at time zone 'UTC','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'-') AS ultimo_mensaje,--SE CONVIERTE A HORARIO DE MEXICO
COALESCE (tlm.latitude||', '|| tlm.longitude, '-') AS ultimascoordenadas,
COALESCE (cgr.desc_georeference,'-') AS localizacion,
CASE 
   WHEN tlm.speed ='' THEN '-' 
ELSE
COALESCE (tlm.speed,'-') --AS velocidad,                         
END AS velocidad,  
CASE 
    WHEN tlm.mileage ='0' THEN '0'
    ELSE
COALESCE (to_char(tlm.mileage,'9,999,999.00'),'-') 
END as odometro, 
COALESCE (formathour(tlm.hour_meter_count),'-') AS horasmotor--verifica si viene null, les asigne un guion "o" en su defecto si encuentra un 0 los elimine
from cat_vehicle cv 
LEFT JOIN cat_vehicle_driver cvd ON cv.origin_adm=cvd.origin_adm and cv.cve_vehicle=cvd.cve_vehicle 
LEFT JOIN cat_employee ce ON cvd.cve_employee=ce.cve_employee and cvd.origin_adm=ce.origin_adm
LEFT JOIN cat_company cc ON cv.origin_adm= cc.origin_adm 
LEFT JOIN tab_lastinc_msg tlm ON cv.origin_adm = tlm.origin_adm AND cv.cve_vehicle = tlm.cve_vehicle
LEFT OUTER JOIN cat_georeference cgr ON tlm.latitude= cgr.lat AND tlm.longitude= cgr.lon
where tlm.send_time BETWEEN (($1::timestamp without time zone)at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Mexico/General') AND (to_timestamp($2,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp without time zone)at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Mexico/General'
--where tlm.send_time BETWEEN $1::timestamp without time zone AND to_timestamp($2,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp without time zone
AND cv.cve_vehicle::TEXT IN (SELECT * FROM json_array_elements_text(JSON_ARRAY_CVES)) AND cv.status='1')det INTO var_jsonresp; 
 RETURN QUERY SELECT var_jsonresp;
 END; 


$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.sp_get_reports_currents_informations(character varying, character varying, character varying)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

En la condición en el `WHERE` ahi no se como se hace la conversión, igual si tienen que ejemplos de como hacer esta conversión se los agradeceria, espero y me puedan ayudar, quedo al pendiente, saludos cordiales

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la condicion de la fecha en formato abreviado

```
WHERE tlm.send_time BETWEEN ($1::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'CST') AND
($2::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'CST')
```

Para ver los tipos de zonas puedes consultar la tabla

SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names;

Saludos

Comment: Hola que tal, probé con esa condición no comprendo a un por que cuando lo ejecuto me trae pocos registros de los que estoy esperando, ya que esa consulta me deberia de traer mas registros ya que va creciendo constantemente ya revise los joins y está todo bien :(